# Read a text file from shared folder in UWP. Access denied exception

Tags: c#, uwp

The below code throws access denied exception.

```
var filename = @"\\MYTSP00491\TestApp\VersionDetails.txt";
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(filename);
var inputStream = await file.OpenSequentialReadAsync();

string fileContents;
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(inputStream.AsStreamForRead()))
{
    fileContents = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your use case here is to read a file from a UNC path. To do so your app will need capabilities appropriate for the network and a File Type Association for the types you need. See the table in the [File access permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions) [Accessing additional locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations) documentation:

> **Universal Naming Convention (UNC) folders**
>
> **A combination of the following capabilities is needed**.
>
> The home and work networks capability: 
>   - *PrivateNetworkClientServer*
>
> And at least one internet and public networks capability: 
>   - *InternetClient* 
>   - *InternetClientServer*
>
> And, if applicable, the domain credentials capability:
>   - *EnterpriseAuthentication*
>
> **Note**: You must add File Type Associations to your app manifest that
>   declare specific file types that your app can access in this location.
>
> **Retrieve a folder using**:  StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync
>
> **Retrieve a file using**:  StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync

Comment: Added all capabilities      <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <uap:Capability Name="enterpriseAuthentication" />   and File Type Associations too <uap:FileTypeAssociation Name="texttypes">
          <uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        <uap:FileType>.txt</uap:FileType>
          </uap:SupportedFileTypes>
        </uap:FileTypeAssociation> Still facing access denied exception.